# convert Facebook.JsonObject into my model

Tags: json, facebook-c#-sdk

i work on app that retrieve information from facebook(list of friend) , when i retrieve a list from facebook ,  want to convert them into my model and after stock them in databse, it's possible to convert Facebook.JsonObject into my model ? :

```
             dynamic myInfo = _fb.Get("/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture");

            dynamic fbfsort = from dynamic friend in (IList<object>) myInfo["data"] 
                              orderby friend.name ascending 
                              select friend;

             foreach (UserFriend friend in fbfsort) {
                    entity.Friends.Add(friend);

                    }
```

Comment: how to convert "fbfsort" into "List<UserFriend>" !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dynamic myInfo = _fb.Get("/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture");

entity.Friends = (
     from dynamic friend 
       in (IList<object>) myInfo["data"] 
  orderby friend.name ascending  
   select new UserFriend()  {
               Id = (long)friend.id, 
               Name = (string)friend.name,
               Picture = (string)friend.picture }
).ToList();
```